# HMR with Angular running as a web worker with platform-webworker

Tags: angular, web-worker

I am attempting to implement a web worker based app using `platformWorkerAppDynamic` etc., but I am having some difficulties implementing HMR.

If I don't call `appModule.destroy()` then HMR actually "works", sort of, in that if I make changes it hot updates and re-renders correctly. However, I am then left with N number of web workers running, where N is the number of times it has hot reloaded. So if I hot reload three times, each button click will action three times.

Conversely, if I employ the usual method for HMR of calling `appModule.destroy()` then the app hot-reloads, and re-renders as expected, but any subsequent UI interaction (like a button click) results in an `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of null.`

For example:

```
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/core';
import { platformWorkerAppDynamic } from '@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from '../app/app.module';
import '../polyfills.ts';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(data => {
        modulePromise.then(appModule => {
            appModule.destroy();
        });
    });
}

const modulePromise = platformWorkerAppDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

What would be the correct way to reload a webworker module?

Answer (score 0):

After much research into this, it turns out the problem lies within Angular's implementation of the webworker in `platform-webworker`; even after destroying the application module, two key listeners are left still attached and listening to now destroyed code: the zone subscription in `PostMessageBusSink` and the event listeners in `PostMessageBusSource`.

I have created a GitHub issue with more details:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24274